# Prevent browser from showing new url when redirected

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to use .htaccess to redirect an url passing an variable, and its working with one exception. I want the browser to display the url posted and not the redirected url.

so if the user post `http://sh.tstr.no/l/u3d68p` I want the redirected to `http://tstr.no/sh/index3.php?load=u3d68p` but I want the posted url to show in the browser.

My .htaccess file is like this

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^sh/l/([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+)? http://tstr.no/sh/index3.php?load=$1 [R,L]
```

I've tried to read examples, but I can't understand what I'm missing.

Hopefully someone here can help, thanks in advance

Comment: It can be done not with the `R` flag, but with `P` flag. (and `mod_proxy`)

Comment: unfortunally mod_proxy isn't provided my server provider... Is there another way round it?